# Azure storage CloudTable.Exists always return false when access with Sas even table exists

Tags: cloud, azure-storage, exists

I noticed `CloudTable.Exists` always return false if access with Sas like below

```
var tableSasCredentials = new StorageCredentials(tableSasToken);
CloudTableClient tableClient = new CloudTableClient(new Uri(tableBaseUrl), tableSasCredentials);
TableServiceContext tableContext = tableClient.GetTableServiceContext();
CloudTable cloudTable = tableClient.GetTableReference(TableName); 
if (clouldTable.Exists())
{
  ...
}
```

The Sas token has Query permission. The table exists, but `cloudTable.Exists()` always return false. Is it a bug? any work around I can know the existence of a table with Sas?

Comment: Hello, I have a similare issue. but in other way:
This test pass:

            string TestTableName = "test" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty);
            // Test Initialize
            CloudTable table = GetCloudTable(TableConnectionString, TestTableName);
            Assert.IsTrue(table.Exists());